# How to catch a pattern that's not in the non-capturing group? - Python

Tags: python, regex, quotation-marks, capturing-group

Given the string:

```
I'll be going home I've the 'v ' isn't want I want to split but I want to catch tokens like 'v and 'w ' .
```

The goal is to catch:

```
'v 
'v
'w
```

But avoid `'ve` and `'ll` and `'t`.

I've tried to catch the `'ve` and `'ll` and `'t` with `(?i)\'(?:ve|ll|t)\b` , e.g.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "I'll be going home I've the 'v ' isn't want I want to split but I want to catch tokens like 'v and 'w ' ."
>>> pattern = r"(?i)\'(?:ve|ll|t)\b"
>>> re.findall(pattern, x)
["'ll", "'ve", "'t"]
```

But I've also tried to negate the non-capturing group in `(?i)\'(?:ve|ll|t)\b` like this `(?i)\'[^(?:ve|ll|t)]\b` but it didn't catch the `'v` and `'w` that is the desired goal.

**How do I catch the substrings that follows the single quote but isn't from a list of pre-defined substring, i.e. `'ll`, `'ve` and `'t` ?**

---

I've tried this too that didn't work:

```
pattern = "(?i)\'(?:[^ve|ll|t|\s])\b"
```

but the `[^...]` only recognize single character and not substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this [one](https://regex101.com/r/a0GiIR/4) will work?

```
\'(?!ve|ll|t|\s)\w+
```

You can use lookahead assertion to filter what you don't want.

## update

In some other languages, the pattern lookahead assert must be fixed length.

That means `(?!ve|t)` is invalid as `ve` and `t` have two different length.

Answer (score 0):

The negative lookahead for non-capturing group is `(?!...)`, so it's something like `(?i)\'(?!ve|ll|t)\w\b`:

```
>>> pattern = r"(?i)\'(?!ve|ll|t)\w\b"
>>> x = "I'll be going home I've the 'v ' isn't want I want to split but I want to catch tokens like 'v and 'w ' ."
>>> re.findall(pattern, x)
["'v", "'v", "'w"]
```